# Multiple plugin instance loading with MEF

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef

In my last application, using MEF to load plugins went just fine, but now I'm running into a new issue.  I have a solution for it that I explain at the end of this question, but I'm looking for other ways to do it.

Let's say I have an interface called ApplianceInterface.  I also have two plugins that inherit from ApplianceInterface, let's call them Blender and Processor.  Now, I would like to have multiple Blenders and Processors in my application, but I am not sure how to instantiate them properly.

Before, I would simply use the `ImportMany` attribute and upon calling ComposeParts, my application would load Blender and Processor.  For example:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(ApplianceInterface))]
private IEnumerable<ApplianceInterface> Appliances { get; set; }
```

and my Blender and Processor plugins would be attributed like this:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[Export(typeof(MyInterface)]
public class Blender : ApplianceInterface
{
    ...
}
```

but what this ends up doing for me is populating Appliances with one Blender and one Processor.  I need to be able to create an arbitrary number of Blender and Processor objects.

Now, from the documentation I understand that `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` is what allows MEF to create a new instance each time, but is there a similar "magical" way to create a specific number of instances of something using MEF?  Up until now, I've relied on `[Import]` and `[ImportMany]` to resolve the assemblies.

Is my only option to use a global container, and then resolve the export manually using GetExportedValue<>?  I have tried GetExportedValue<> and that implementation does work fine for me, but I was just curious if there is a better, more accepted way to do it.

**UPDATE**

I just realized a big mistake, and GetExportedValue<> isn't what I really want.  I'm iterating over an IEnumerable, and when I get a match (based on some parameters), I want to instantiate a new object of the current value.  GetExportedValue<> ends up failing in the case where I have two different plugins that both export ApplianceInterface.

I think my question is different now, and is probably a C# specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExportFactory is what you are looking for, but it is currently only available in Silverlight.  Here is a question that explains how to handle this on the desktop: [Multiple Instances of a single MEF DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878265/multiple-instances-of-a-single-mef-dll)

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach.  So use MEF to resolve a single instance of a class factory which can then create multiple instances of a specific type.  I think it would work fine, but does require more implementation that simply calling GetExportedValue.

My appliance creation all occurs in a single object that manages all of the appliances in the kitchen, so the MEF container is only needed in that one assembly.  However, if things change and I need to resolve elsewhere, I think your suggestion is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It looks like this works for my question before I realized a fundamental flaw in my thinking (or lack thereof).  I could possibly extend it to handle my new issue as well, but it's not the best solution.  When I have two ApplianceInterfaces, I could pass a string to the class factory to get a specific type of ApplianceInterface, because there could be multiple plugins that expose this interface, yet I need to be able to create an instance of the derived class.  There's got to be a way to do this with C# magic but I haven't figured it out yet.