# MEF instance management

Tags: c#, wpf, instance, mef

I am working on application that has multiple modules and sub modules. Here's what I need to do:

1. ModuleA has a sub module SubModuleA, SubModuleB, SubModuleC.
2. I want to export ModuleA, SubModuleA, SubModuleB, SubModuleC.
3. ModuleA can have multiple instances.
4. Whenever I import ModuleA inside the sub modules, I want to get the correct instance and also when I import SubModuleA,SubModuleB and SubModuleC inside other classes.

How can I manage that scenario using MEF? Do I really need to use MEF.

Updated: 
Here's a quick example:

```
public class School
{
    List<Classroom> classRooms { get; set; }
}

[Export]
public class Classroom
{
    List<Teacher> teachers { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    List<Student> students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Import]
    Classroom classroom { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I want to export the classroom class because I need to import it in the Student class, let's just say that I really need the classroom class inside the student class. I want to skip the part where we pass the classroom to the teacher and from the teacher we'll pass it to the student. But when I import classroom, I want to have the correct instance where that class room contains the teacher of the student.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't necessarily follow the usage scenario. Can you give a clearer example source code. Another question is whether you need to use MEF, would an IoC container such as Ninject, Windsor help. Is there some runtime distinction on the actual type you want?

Comment: Only if you could be clear with your scenario, you can expect better answers. Anyway, to point 3: Refer this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878265/multiple-instances-of-a-single-mef-dll?rq=1) answer..

Comment: Hi guys, I already updated the question with a simple example. Do I really need to use mef in this kind of scenario?