# MEF2 - Create multiple instances with ExportFactory<>

Tags: c#, dll, mef, factory, multiple-instances

I have multiple dlls and I'd like to create new non-shared instances according to some parameters. [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878265/multiple-instances-of-a-single-mef-dll) should be good for me as well but creation should take a parameter to decide which type to create and I want to use ExportFactory to be able to dispose created instances, too.

So far I have a component, that loads exported dlls:

```
regisBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();

regisBuilder.ForType<WPProvider>().Export<WPProvider>();

dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, regisBuilder);
agrCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(dirCatalog);

container = new CompositionContainer(agrCatalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);
container.ComposeParts();
```

I think WPProvider should be a good task to ExportFactory but I don't know how. Now I have this class:

```
public class WPProvider
    {
        ExportFactory<IDCPlugin> _factory;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public WPProvider(ExportFactory<IDCPlugin> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        public IDCPlugin CreateInstance()
        {
            return _factory.CreateExport().Value;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I have more dlls, the _container.GetExportedValue(); row throws a CompositionException because it founds more than one types with the IDCPlugin contract. I thought ExportFactory is created and gives me the objects when I want them.
This way _provider would be an IEnumerable containing all the exports. **But how does this behave like a factory?**

**Basically I need a good example of selecting by type (or attributes) and creating multiple instances of that type with MEF2 ExportFactory and RegistrationBuilder.**

Comment: Finally I've got a solution using this method:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488297/how-do-you-use-exportfactoryt